# is possible to change @State property's value through its structure's method?

Tags: swift, swiftui

at Xcode's play ground I run code below:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Test {
    @State var count: Int = 0   //to avoid "mutating" keyword, I use "@State" property wrapper
    func countUp() {
        self.count += 1
    }
}

var test = Test()
test.countUp()     // I want "count" property to be count up. but it did not
print(test.count)  // print 0
```

Q) why test.count is still 0??

Comment: `Expressions are not allowed at the top level`, so how does that work *at all*? That being said, you can't access `@State` properties from outside the `struct` like that. You'll probably need to look into the `@Published` property wrapper.

Comment: what a simple & powerful comment! really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the intent of the question, but I will explain why the code in question does not work.(I believe this is the same thing [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848526/is-possible-to-change-state-propertys-value-through-its-structures-method/67855208#comment119924465_67848526).)

You are using `SwiftUI` in a playground and not `View`.
The `@State` conforms to `DynamicProperty`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty

The  Documents say:

> You should only access a state property from inside the view’s body, or from methods called by it.

> An interface for a stored variable that updates an external property of a view.
> and
> The view gives values to these properties prior to recomputing the view’s body.

It has been suggested to use it with `View` and `view’s body`.

As mentioned above, your code does not use `View` or `view’s body`.

Since `@State` can only be used in a `struct`, if you want to do something similar, you can use a `class` and use `@Published` as shown below(simple use `Combine`, not `SwiftUI`):

```
import Combine

class Test {
    @Published var count: Int = 0
    func countUp() {
        self.count += 1
    }
}

var test = Test()
test.countUp()
print(test.count) // 1
```

However, your code has no one to subscribe to the changes, so this is just an experimental code.

Answer (score 1):

> Expressions are not allowed at the top level.

To test your case I created a `View` struct called `Test1`, and within its initialiser I created object for `Test` view. Check code below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test1:View {

    init() {
        let test = Test() // concentrate on this
        test.countUp()     
    }

    var body: some View {
        Test() // Ignore for now
    }
}
```

**Test View-:**

```
import SwiftUI


@propertyWrapper struct TestCount:DynamicProperty {
    @State private var count = 0
    var wrappedValue: Int {
        get {
            count
        }
        nonmutating set {
           count = newValue
        }
    }

    init(_ count: Int) {
        self.count = count
    }
}

struct Test: View {

    @TestCount var count:Int
    
    init(count:Int) {
        _count = TestCount(count)
        print(_count)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            countUp()
        } label: {
            Text("\(count)")
        }
    }

     func countUp()  {
        count += 1
        print(count)
    }

}
```

For better understanding I created a custom `propertyWrapper` and we will initialise that inside `Test` view.

Now, when you run this code in simulator `Test1` view is called first, and in it’s initialiser it will create object for `Test()` view.

`Test` view upon initialisation will create object for it’s property wrapper called `TestCount`, once created it will print description for `TestCount` instance, and **notice** the print output now-:

> TestCount(_count: SwiftUI.State<Swift.Int>(_value: 0, _location: nil))

You can clearly see **State** variable `count` inside `TestCount` wrapper was assigned default value 0, but wasn’t allocated any `SwiftUI.StoredLocation` yet.

Now, this line is executed next `test.countUp()` in `Test1` view, and because we are calling it from outside of body property and `Test1` is also initialised outside of `body` property , compiler is smart enough to detect that and it will not provide SwiftUI storage location for this change to `count` variable, because there is no view update required for this change, hence you always see **Output** as `0` (default saved value).

To prove my point, now make following change in `Test1` view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test1:View {

//    init() {
//        let test = Test(count: 0)
//        test.countUp()     // I want "count" property to be count up. but it did not
//    }

    var body: some View {
        Test(count: 0)
    }
}
```

Now again the initial print statement inside Test view is same -:

> TestCount(_count: SwiftUI.State<Swift.Int>(_value: 0, _location: nil))

But, now you have a view with `Button` to change the `count` variable value on tap.

When you tap the button, again countUp() will be called, and this time check the output of print statement again, SwiftUI storage location is no more nil.

> TestCount(_count: SwiftUI.State<Swift.Int>(_value: 0, _location:
> Optional(SwiftUI.StoredLocation<Swift.Int>))).

You can debug the code further to get more better understanding, and I would also suggest you to read about `PropertyWrappers` in more detail, and how they work internally.